# "Équation de Maxwell-Thomson"

Tags: electromagnetism, maxwell, magnetism

In French, Gauss' law for magnetism (no magnetic monopoles) is, sometimes at least, referred to as *Équation de Maxwell-Thomson*. What is the historical justification of this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In French, physical laws are not always named the same as in English (usually some Frenchman is added)

- Snell's law $\to$ *loi de Snell-Descartes*
- Gauss' theorem $\to$ *théorème de Ostrogradski-Gauss*
- WKB aproximation $\to$ *approximation BKW* (Léon Brillouin has to come first)
- Boyle's law $\to$ *loi de Boyle-Mariotte* or *loi de Mariotte*
- Rouché-Capelli theorem $\to$ *théorème de Rouché–Fontené*
- Motor effect (force) $\to$ *force de Laplace*
- Addition of two vectors $\to$ *relation de Chasles*

As for *l'équation de Maxwell-Thomson*, in French all of Maxwell's equations start with Maxwell: *Maxwell-Gauss, Maxwell-Faraday, Maxwell-Ampère, Maxwell-Thomson*. The latter refers to Lord Kelvin (William Thomson), see ref 1. Kelvin contributed greatly to electromagnetism, so it is hard to tell why is he honored with this equation. However, he did one very important related thing. In 1846, Kelvin showed the common relation between the magnetic field $\mathbf B$ and the magnetic vector potential $\mathbf A$, that is
$$\mathbf B=\nabla \times \mathbf A\;,$$
which directly implies *l'équation de Maxwell–Thomson*,
$$\nabla \cdot \mathbf B=0\;,$$
because it is the divergence of a curl. I would have preferred *Maxwell-Kelvin* but it is going to be hard to track who coined the name.

References:

- [Crysos, Electromagnétisme IUT](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Electromagn%C3%A9tisme/8ufMDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%C3%A9quation%20Maxwell-Thomson%20histoire&pg=PA4&printsec=frontcover)
- [Chen Ning Yang, *The conceptual origins of Maxwell’s equations and gauge theory*,Physics Today 2014](https://doi.org/10.1063%2FPT.3.2585)